# sequelize nested include There is an entry for table , but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize and a nested include. I want the table `ModelC` to be joined with the table `ModelB` on `id` and with `ModelA` on `SomeColumnId`. Tables `ModelC` and `ModelA` have no associations to each other, but they both have associations to `ModelB` (hasMany-belongsTo).
This is my code so far:

```js
const model = await ModelA.findAll({
    include: {
        model: ModelB,
        include: {
            model: ModelC,
            where: {
                [Op.and]: [
                    sequelize.literal(
                        '"ModelB->ModelC"."SomeColumnId" = "ModelA"."SomeColumnId"'
                    ),
                ],
            },
        },
    },
    subQuery: false,
    raw: true,
});
```

But it gives me an error:

```
Invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "ModelA".
There is an entry for table "ModelA", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this.

```js
const model = await ModelA.findAll({
    include: {
        model: ModelB,
        raw: true,
        include: {
            model: ModelC,
            required: false,
            where: {
                SomeColumnId: [sequelize.literal('"ModelA"."SomeColumnId"')],
            },
        },
    },
});
```